# Get temp path with scape characters

Tags: c#, escaping

How can I get the path from `Path.GetTempPath()` in a format like this:

```
C:\\Users\\m3\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\
```

Not like this:

```
C:\Users\m3\AppData\Local\Temp\
```

I mean I want it with `\` scape characters. Is there an automatic way? Or do I have to add `\` characters myself?

I need to write the path to a file and the `\` characters have to be `\\`.

Comment: Why do you need it in that 'format'?. Usually showing two slashes is just an artifact of the debugger when it shows you a string variable.

Comment: @Steve Yes, I need it in \\ format. I'm going to write it to a Python file with \\ format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple way to double the separator char in a path is the following

```
var psep = Path.DirectorySeparatorChar;
var p = Path.GetTempPath().Replace($"{psep}", $"{psep}{psep}");
Console.WriteLine(p);
```

Comment: Only works if the character is `\ ` as `/` does not need escaping.

Comment: Really it is not clear why they need escaping at all. The return value from GetTempPath is surely assigned to a variable. So the reason for the double \ should be something connected at how the output file is used.

Answer (score 1):

Use string.Replace:

```cs
string tempPath = Path.GetTempPath();
string formattedPath = tempPath.Replace(@"\", @"\\");
```

Or Path.DirectorySeparatorChar:

```cs
string tempPath = Path.GetTempPath();
string formattedPath = tempPath.Replace(Path.DirectorySeparatorChar.ToString(), Path.DirectorySeparatorChar + @"\");
```

Both methods work fine, tested in vscode polyglot notebooks C#:

```
using System.IO; 
string tempPath = Path.GetTempPath(); 
string formattedPath = tempPath.Replace(@"\", @"\\"); 
Console.WriteLine(formattedPath);
```

Returns: `C:\\Users\\name\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\`

```
using System.IO;
string tempPath = Path.GetTempPath(); 
string formattedPath = tempPath.Replace(Path.DirectorySeparatorChar.ToString(), Path.DirectorySeparatorChar + @"\"); 
Console.WriteLine(formattedPath);
```

Returns:
`C:\\Users\\name\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\`

Comment: When replacing, using the `Path.DirectorySeparatorChar` might be preferred in may case.

Comment: Ok cool, I added that method

Comment: Let me test it...

Comment: Both methods work fine